# "Forwarding" keypresses from an applet to a JFrame

Tags: java, applet, jframe, keylistener

I have a JFrame which contains a JApplet. There are shortcut keys that I have configured for the JFrame that work fine when the focus is on some panel of it, but once I click into the applet, none of the shortcut keys work anymore. Is there any way that I can forward these key presses to the JFrame so that the events are still fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by running `applet.setFocusable(false);` before adding it to the JFrame.